# Executable named '[' in /usr/bin in Google colab Jupyter Notebook

Tags: bash, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Trying to dive a little bit deeper into Jupyter Notebooks, I noticed a strange program located in /usr/bin on the virtual machine of the Google colab:

```
!ls -alF /usr/bin|head -4
```

returned

```
total 288128
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root        4096 Jul 27 13:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root        4096 Jul 27 13:54 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       51632 Feb  7  2022 [*
```

I've tried executing it but only succeeded in getting a "missing `]' " error.

Does anyone know what this `[` executable is?

Comment: Nothing specific to Jupyter or Collaboratory about this; every UNIX system has it.

Comment: In general, btw, this class of curiosity question about the OS is better placed on [unix.se]; Stack Overflow is only for questions about narrow, specific problems that prevent you from accomplishing something in the course of writing code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I don't have access to too many UNIX systems these days and this executable never caught my eye in the past. So I thought it to be something special in the context of a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It's an alias for `test`, so that you can write

```bash
if [ expr ]; then
```

The implementation of shells is often ... fun.  As your error shows, `[` is a program which builds up an expression to evaluate from all the arguments it is passed preceding `]`  (If you pass anything after ] you get a different error).  Then it builds up an expression to evaluate, and returns 0 if the expression evaluates to true, and 1 otherwise.  (Yes: 0 for true.  *That* dates (at least) to `c`, which adopted this as a decent hack for returning status in a world without exceptions.)

Incidentally this explains the `;` in the if paradigm: `then` is really a new line, and `if` has *evaluated* what comes after.

If this kind of thing interests you, spend a while browser retrocomputing.SE.  There are *lots* of fun details in historic systems.

This has nothing to do with colab btw: run `which [` on any *nix machine.

As @CharlesDuffy notes, `[` is generally a [builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) today (as is e.g. `true`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy first is a good point, second is so poorly expressed as to be wrong in my answer; ta.  obv if [ (or any command) could stop consuming we wouldn't need ;

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I had tried calling the program to find out more but the "missing ]" error looked like a shell error to me because [ and ] have special meaning in (ba)sh. Escaping via \ didn't seem to work either, but I attributed this to calling into shell from python.
Now I know. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2206916, `[[` unambiguously has special meaning in bash, but less so `[` -- the latter is handled by bash's parser in the same way that any other command is at parse time, and bash's built-in `[` command is intended to work _exactly_ the same way `/usr/bin/[` does (having the builtin is a performance enhancement intended not to change behavior in any way other than efficiency). Indeed, people thinking `[` is syntax instead of treating it as a command (needing spaces around the arguments, correct quoting, etc) is a common source of bugs.